# How can I use jQuery to replace the content of an attribute inside of a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have this code:

```
<textarea class="mapCode">
<    area shape="rect" coords="" href="http://www.sitehere" target="_self">
</textarea>
```

How can I use jQuery to insert/update values into the coords attribute even if it's not empty?

Right now I'm using...

```
return $(this).text().replace("coords=\"\"", 'coords="'+selection.x1+','+selection.y1+','+selection.x2+','+selection.y2+'"');
```

But of course that only works one time since it's always looking for an empty `coords=""` attribute.

Comment: As a side note: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1414562

Comment: True. However, in this case the parsed HTML is very limited, making RegEx a feasible and especially fast option to solve this problem (see also the second answer to the posted question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/1595029)

Comment: @irruputuncu ya in this case regex should be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap textarea content in a jQuery object then use any relevant method to update it, e.g:

```
var $content = $('<div/>').html($('.mapCode').val());
$content.find('area').attr('coords', selection.x1+','+selection.y1+','+selection.x2+','+selection.y2);

$('.mapCode').val($content.html());
```

### -DEMO-

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regular expression with a wildcard in your replace call:

```
$(this).text().replace(/coords=".*"/gi, 'coords="..."');
```

This will work with both an empty and a set coords attribute.

Answer (score -1):

```
<textarea class="mapCode">
   <area id="myArea" shape="rect" coords="" href="http://www.sitehere" target="_self">
</textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    var myArea = $('#myArea');
    myArea.attr('coords', selection.x1+','+selection.y1+','+selection.x2+','+selection.y2);

});​
```

Comment: you can't manipulate a textarea that way.....will eat my words though if you provide a working demo